# Spring Cloud Config Client not working with spring boot 2.5.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Spring cloud config client not working with Spring Boot 2.5.1 but working with 2.5.0.

application-dev.yml

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    import: configserver:http://localhost:8270/
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
```

Error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Config data location 'configserver:http://localhost:8270/' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'configserver:http://localhost:8270/' at class path resource [application-dev.yml] - 3:13 is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'
```

pom.xml

```xml
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

I am running Spring Cloud Config Server with Spring boot 2.4.4 and Spring Cloud version 2020.0.1

Comment: Can you post your pom as well? helps to replicate the issue at it is

Comment: facing the same problem. Spring boot 2.5.0 was working fine. While 2.5.1 is not able to fetch props from config server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a [regression](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26960) in Spring Boot 2.4.7 and 2.5.1. The regression means that the import will not work when it’s declared in a profile-specific file. Until it has been fixed you could stay on an earlier version of Boot or temporarily move the import to `application.yml`.