# Config data location 'configserver:http://localhost:8888/' does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

My config server is running on localhost:8888 but when i try to fetch configs from my config server ,its shows this error

```
Config data location 'configserver:http://localhost:8888/' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'configserver:http://localhost:8888/' at class path resource 
[application.properties] - 2:22 is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'
```

my other microservice has this application.properties

```
spring.application.name=limits-service
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888/
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Not sure of your springboot version, but could you see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045201/spring-cloud-config-client-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-5-1

Comment: Show your dependencies please

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after removing text configserver from

> spring.config.import properties

Before
`spring.config.import=configserver:http://localehost:8080/`

After
`spring.config.import=http://localehost:8080/`

Comment: it's not work on spring boot 3.1.5 with spring cloud 2022.0.4